# How do I get the C# IErrorDataInfo to work with ASP.MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I've verified my IErrorDataInfo implementation on my Model works but I can't seem to get the validations error from IErrorDataInfo on my model to the ASP.MVC ModelState in my controller.  What is the best way to do this?

I could loop through my results and manually add them to the ModelState but there has to be an easier way.

Here is my controller from the client.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Grade grade)
    {
        MvcApplication.Container.BuildUp(grade);

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Edit", grade);
        }

        try
        {
            var provider = MvcApplication.Container.Resolve<IGradeProvider>();
            provider.Edit(grade);

            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Grade", new { id = grade.GradeId });
        }
        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

Here is my IErrorDataInfo implimentation

```
public abstract class AbstractBase : IAbstractBase
{
    #region IDataErrorInfo

    public abstract ValidationResult SelfValidate();

    public bool IsValid
    {
        get
        {
            return SelfValidate().IsValid;
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            var results = SelfValidate().Errors.Select(s => string.Format("● {0}{1}", s.ErrorMessage, Environment.NewLine)).ToArray();
            return string.Join("", results);
        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            var validationResults = SelfValidate();
            if (validationResults == null) return string.Empty;
            var columnResults = validationResults.Errors.FirstOrDefault(x => string.Compare(x.PropertyName, columnName, true) == 0);
            return columnResults != null ? columnResults.ErrorMessage : string.Empty;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

UPDATE:

I should have added that I'm using dependency injection.  The problem was not that the IErrorDataInfo was not working with ASP.MVC 3, the problem was that IErrorDataInfo need an injected parameter to work correctly.  To fix the issue I manually called TryValidateModel after the buildup of the object but before the ModelState.IsValid is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataErrorInfoModelValidatorProvider is using Item member of IDataErrorInfo for gathering property level validation errors and Error property for Model level validation error:

```
public string Error
{
  //This is needed for model level validation to work
  get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

public string this[string propertyName]
{
  //This is needed for property level validation to work
  get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

This all should work out of the box (if you haven't disabled the DataErrorInfoModelValidatorProvider) when properly implemented.

UPDATE:

If your model isn't ready for validation during the model binding process (or you don't want it to be binded by ASP.NET MVC), you need to manually validate the model before you call the ModelState.IsValid method. Your controller might look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Grade grade)
{
  MvcApplication.Container.BuildUp(grade);

  //Add this to your controller.
  TryValidateModel(grade);

  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View("Edit", grade);
  }

  try
  {
    var provider = MvcApplication.Container.Resolve<IGradeProvider>();
    provider.Edit(grade);

    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Grade", new { id = grade.GradeId });
  }
  catch
  {
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
}
```

Comment: i thought it should work out of the box.  let me check the provider.

Comment: Please share the Grade class implementation.

Comment: I verified the IErrorDataInfo-ified Grade class is being called by mvc after all.  Look like I asked the wrong question. I'm using Dependency Injection in my Models and It looks like the Grade Model is not built up at the time ASP.MVC 3 call the this[string propertyName] method.  I guess the real issue is I need to inject my dependencies before the controller calls the method.  Hmmm.

Comment: @Keith For validation to work your grade parameter can't be injected at all, it has to be build by ASP.NET MVC from the request (the validation occurs while the ModelBinder is getting values through ValueProvider and building the model).

Comment: @Keith As an alternative you can manually trigger the validation inside your action by using Controller.ValidateModel (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356131.aspx)